# Cannot set property 'dcSlickTabs' of undefined- jQuery Conflict issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my jQuery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function($){

                    $("#'.$tag.'").dcFlickr({
                    limit: '.$nFlickr.', 
                    style: "thumb",
                    q: {id: "'.$id.'",
                        lang: "en-us",
                        format: "json",
                        jsoncallback: "?"}
                    });
        });
    </script>
```

It shows me this error Cannot set property 'dcSlickTabs' of undefined
I tried this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
        $j(document).ready(function() {

                    $j("#'.$tag.'").dcFlickr({
                    limit: '.$nFlickr.', 
                    style: "thumb",
                    q: {id: "'.$id.'",
                        lang: "en-us",
                        format: "json",
                        jsoncallback: "?"}
                    });
        });
    </script>
```

But still its not working ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you are trying to write some sort of combination of PHP and js.  String concatenation in js is done with + and . in PHP.

Example:

```
//js
var str = 'Str' + 'ing';

//PHP
$str = 'Str'.'ing';
```

Comment: If this is all in a PHP file, you need to echo the values of the js.  If it is an HTML file, you need to access the variables in a <?php...?> sequence.